# Odoo 10 :Creating Security rules for custom module

Tags: xml, security, odoo, usergroups

**Goal** : To add an option in the user form that has the label ‘Demo module access’ with a drop down menu to choose the security groups for a custom module.

**Model name** : simcard_simcard

**Module name** : simcard

my ir.model.access.csv :

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
demo_admin, Model admin access,model_simcard_simcard,simcard.group_manager,1,1,1,1
demo_user, Model user access,model_simcard_simcard,simcard.group_user,1,0,0,0
```

and my security>user_groups.xml :

```
    <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_management">
    <field name="name">Demo module access</field>
    <field name="description">User access level for this module</field>
    <field name="sequence">3</field>
</record>

<record id="group_user" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">User</field>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
    <field name="category_id" ref="simcard.module_management"/>
</record>

<record id="group_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Manager</field>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('simcard.group_user'))]"/>
    <field name="category_id" ref="simcard.module_management"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

My manifest file :

```
# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base'],

    # always loaded
    'data': [
        'security/user_groups.xml',
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/views.xml',
        'views/templates.xml',
    ],

    'qweb': ['static/xml/tree_view_button.xml'],

    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [
        'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,
}
```

And i got this error :

```
    018-10-10 11:00:32,234 8890 ERROR test werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo-env10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo-env10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 181, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/service/server.py", line 245, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 186, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 172, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 1326, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 1300, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo-env10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/http.py", line 1482, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/__init__.py", line 52, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 59, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 83, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 373, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 270, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
    _load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 96, in _load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 845, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/Users/anubhavjhalani/odoo10/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 898, in convert_xml_import
    doc = etree.parse(xmlfile)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:85131)

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1803, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:124287)

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1823, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:124599)

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1718, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:123258)

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1139, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:117808)

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 573, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:110510)

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:112276)

  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 613, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:111124)

XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 7, column 1
```

Am i missing something ? this error is coming from user_groups.xml.

Comment: Can you update your question with manifest file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, User has limited access right compare to Manager. So manger has more privilege of root access right.

I have updated it so try with following code:

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="module_management">
    <field name="name">Demo module access</field>
    <field name="description">User access level for this module</field>
    <field name="sequence">3</field>
</record>

<record id="group_user" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">User</field>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
    <field name="category_id" ref="user_access_rights_demo.module_management"/>
</record>

<record id="group_manager" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Manager</field>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('user_access_rights_demo.group_user'))]"/>
    <field name="category_id" ref="user_access_rights_demo.module_management"/>
    <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
</record>
```

Other then your code is ok to me.

**NOTE**

These two files `.xml and .csv` must be listed in `__manifest__.py` as other view files are given. Something like,

```
'data': [
    'security/user_groups.xml',
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
]
```

Afterwards, restart Odoo service and upgrade *simcard_simcard* module.

Comment: i tried this but menu still doesnt appear in the user form and also no error in logs

Comment: Can you write some wrong tag in your security file ? to make sure it execute properly when you upgrade module.

Comment: i found some mistakes in my code. I have updated my question.Please check

Answer (score 0):

You must add this parameter in the **manifest**.py or **openerp**.py file `'application': True,`

Answer (score 0):

fixed my problem with this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_management">
      <field name="name">Demo module access</field>
      <field name="description">User access level for this module</field>
      <field name="sequence">3</field>
    </record>

   <record id="group_user" model="res.groups">
     <field name="name">User</field>
     <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
     <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
     <field name="category_id" ref="simcard.module_management"/>
    </record>

    <record id="group_manager" model="res.groups">
      <field name="name">Manager</field>
      <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('simcard.group_user'))]"/>
      <field name="category_id" ref="simcard.module_management"/>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```